# Connecting multiple DACs to SPI bus but all SPI ports are in use

Tags: stm32, spi, dac

I am trying to setup multiple DACs (4 channel, TLV5620) at the same time with an STM32. My project requires 5 channels, but all SPI ports are currently in use. TLV5620 doesn't support a daisy chain configuration. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The TLV5620 has a simple shift-load architecture so it doesn't strictly requires a SPI, anyway.

It all depends on the update rate you are aiming for and your need for synchronous updates (the LDAC pin helps for that).

From the data diagrams it seems that it simply keeps the last 11 bits received and load them with a pulse; that would be the easiest implementation too (a free shift register and the load clocking the holding registers). TI can confirm it, just ask in their forum.

So simply tie all the clocks and data together and pulse the individual loads after each configuration word. LDAC last if you need synchronous update.

Another way would be to gate the clock and do a single load. More complex but the DAC wouldn't even see other's data, if it actually were a problem.

Of course you could also use another MCU or even a low density FPGA to handle all your 'excess' peripheral, when you have a lot of them it's easier and cheaper than discrete logic and I/O expanders.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 5 channel output is being controlled by touch. so adding anaother MCU wont work.can you explain bit further ? i tried to keep LDAC,LOAD,DATA,SCK common for both the DAC. and OUTPUT i am getting is same in both the DAC as expected.

Comment: You neet to keep the LOAD separated: clock the first data, LOAD on first, clock the second data, LOAD on second, LDAC for sync\

Comment: Issue resolved. now i am able control 5 channels independently. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Very few SPI devices support daisy chaining.

So put them in parallel on the same bus like you normally do when putting multiple SPI devices on the same bus.

Comment: That DAC hasn't even a proper SPI, it's just a shift-load register. And no ouput. So it's a simple tie-all-together ordeal.

Comment: thank you for the response. Keeping it in parallel configuration would give same output like ((voltage of ch1 in DAC1= voltage of ch1 in DAC2).I kept LDAC,LOAD,SCK,DATA common for both the DAC.